# How to get the type of Win32Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

How do I get the type of `Win32Exception`, and classify it into something more specific? The message is only (arguably) good for showing it to the user.

- Should I use `Win32Exception.ErrorCode`, `Win32Exception.HResult`, or `Win32Exception.NativeErrorCode`?
- Are there any built-in enumerations for these codes?

Comment: NativeErrorCode returns the underlying winapi error code.  Enumerated in the SDK's WinError.h file and many web sites.  There are many of them, you have to know up front which one you are going to "handle".  As always, only swallow exceptions when you know how to restore program state and take corrective action that doesn't require the user to help.  Not common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that to classify `Win32Exception` you should use use both:

- `Win32Exception.ErrorCode` ([HRESULT value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137(v=vs.85).aspx))
- `Win32Exception.NativeErrorCode` ([system error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx))

The exception message is a culture-specific translation of system error code, so don't use it. There are no built-in .NET classes for the mentioned values, you have to make your own.

*Example:* [how to catch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40830207/633969) a specific "The system cannot find the file specified" kind of `Win32Exception`.